# Access view of ChildView in activity

Tags: android

I am using the [Expanding-Collection-Library](https://github.com/Ramotion/expanding-collection-android) which uses the method

```
public void instantiateCard(LayoutInflater inflaterService, final ViewGroup head, ListView list, ECCardData data)
```

to instantiate all the views of inside the head ViewGroup.
I change the visibility of a few views inside this method, depending, on whether the card is fully expanded or collapsed.

I want to collapse the cards in the activity's `onBackPressed()`, which works fine, but I cannot change the visibility of the child views of the head ViewGroup.
I tried accessing the views by declaring class variables inside MainActivity which are then set in `instantiateCard()` and though I get no errors that the view cannot be found nothing happens on visibility change.
The same when trying to define separate variables inside the activity and `instantiateCard` and setting them independently.

```
@Override
public void instantiateCard(LayoutInflater inflaterService, final ViewGroup head, ListView list, ECCardData data) {
    final LinearLayout headerButtonContainer = head.findViewById(R.id.headerButtonContainer);
    final LinearLayout nameContainer = head.findViewById(R.id.nameContainer);
    final TextView tvAailablePlacesHead = head.findViewById(R.id.tvAvailablePlacesHead);
    final TextView tvNameHead = head.findViewById(R.id.tvNameHead);

// here I also tried setting the activities variables like
// tvAcNameHead = tvNameHead;
// since just decalring a field variable and using it like
// nameHeadFieldVariable = head.findViewById(R.id.tvNameHead);
// would lead to not being able to change the visibility here either

    // Card toggling by click on head element
    head.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            ecPagerView.toggle();
                if (headerButtonContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        setDetailOverlayItemsVisible(headerButtonContainer, nameContainer, tvNameHead, tvAailablePlacesHead);
                    } else {
                        setDetailOverlayItemsInvisible(headerButtonContainer, nameContainer, tvNameHead, tvAailablePlacesHead);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: can you post some parts of your code where you manage to change visibility of the header elements?

Comment: @maheryhaja I added the code

Comment: which class does setDetailOverlayItemsVisible(...) belong to? sorry for late answer, working on your issue

Comment: MainActivity in which `instantiateCard()`is called